# delete [stop-words] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I came through this tag today [stop-words](/questions/tagged/stop-words). There are some questions tagged with this, but IMO this tag individually should not exist in the first place.

It has **0 followers** and has **no tag wiki.**

Shouldn't it be deleted?

Comment: It has 113 questions. Why do you say that no followers and wiki mean that it should be deleted?

Comment: @RaghavSood by followers i mean no body has starred that tag. And that tag does not make sense? How would you interpret this tag?

Comment: downvoter please comment so that i can understand where I am wrong. I am new to meta and trying to be helpful.

Comment: @NarendraPathai: Downvote is disagreeement, not that you did anything wrong.

Comment: @NarendraPathai Remember that votes work differently on Meta, they're simply an "I Agree" or a "I Disagree".

Comment: Can anyone suggest be an edit to this question to make it more appropriate?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @0A0D ok then i would not change it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree, I think it should stay. It is already used by 100+ questions and they are valid use cases.

I've added a tag wiki entry for it and a brief explanation of the topic itself. If anyone feels like improving it, feel free :). I don't have the reputation to auto-edit, so my edit is pending review.

Comment: Thanks. I would remove the question.

Comment: @NarendraPathai I wouldn't say remove the question, you have highlighted the need for the tag wiki to be in place.

Comment: It would be nice if you can edit the question or suggest me an edit.

Comment: I'll suggest one for you (as I don't want my edit to be rejected for vandalism). I'd re-word it to say how the wiki needs an explanation and more information around it.